# Selenium : Executing same line some time work some time does not work

Tags: java, selenium

Below is my code: when ever i run this code some times it execute 10 lines some other time executes more than 20 line.
When ever issue occur it stops with error " no such element" found. 
I think it is due to reload or page wait time. not sure please help me if you can :)

Error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element,
WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 20.06 seconds
```

---

```
    WebDriver HP=new ChromeDriver();
    HP.get("https://**********************/");
    HP.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    HP.manage().window().maximize();
    HP.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    HP.findElement(By.linkText("Northland")).click();
    HP.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    HP.navigate().back();
    HP.findElement(By.linkText("Auckland")).click();
    HP.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    HP.navigate().back();
    HP.findElement(By.linkText("Waikato")).click();
    HP.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    HP.navigate().back();
    HP.findElement(By.linkText("Bay of Plenty")).click();
    HP.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    HP.navigate().back();
    HP.findElement(By.linkText("Gisborne")).click();
    HP.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    HP.navigate().back();
    HP.findElement(By.linkText("Hawkes Bay")).click();
    HP.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    HP.navigate().back();
```

Comment: you would have to give the whole exception (including stack-trace), and give all the code (and not more) necessary to track the error, and make sure that we can know which line in the code is which line number in the files (as it appears in the stack-trace)

Comment: If i run this code some time it hits in line 20 some time it hits line 30 . it is not exactly the same line it is occurring.

Comment: I cannot able to copy the error in a single instance:

Comment: i am very sure there is no issue in the code but there is some time interval issue but don't know how to solve

Comment: `.implicitWait()` doesn't actually wait, it sets the default wait time. You only need to do that once. Check the Selenium docs for more info: [link](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#implicit-waits)

Comment: The issue is most likely a timing issue. Sometimes 20s isn't enough time to wait. When it's not enough time, the script tries to click an element that doesn't exist... thus the error. You should add some proper waits and adjust the wait times so that it waits long enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As correctly stated by *JeffC* in your question's comment section:

> `.implicitWait()` doesn't actually wait, it sets the default wait time. You only need to do that once. Check the Selenium docs for more info: [link](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#implicit-waits)

You need to explicitly wait for the link to be accessible (like *Asit Tripathy*'s answer demonstrates) with something like this:

```
new WebDriverWait(this.driver, 20, 1)
        .until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(linkSelector));
```

In your specific context that would mean something like the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    WebDriver HP=new ChromeDriver();
    HP.get("https://**********************/");
    HP.manage().window().maximize();
    clickLinkAndGoBack(HP, "Northland");
    clickLinkAndGoBack(HP, "Auckland");
    clickLinkAndGoBack(HP, "Waikato");
    clickLinkAndGoBack(HP, "Bay of Plenty");
    clickLinkAndGoBack(HP, "Gisborne");
    clickLinkAndGoBack(HP, "Hawkes Bay");
}

private void clickLinkAndGoBack(WebDriver driver, String linkText) {
    ExpectedCondition<WebElement> condition;
    condition = ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.linkText(linkText));
    WebElement link = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20, 1).until(condition);
    link.click();
    // actually do something after clicking (check displayed ...?)
    driver.navigate().back();
}
```

Comment: Better understanding of webdriverwait: http://www.assertselenium.com/webdriver/webdriver-wait-commands/

Answer (score 0):

In your complete code you are running as Data Driven

```
Loop Start 
{

HP.findElement(By.linkText("**Your LinkText**")).click();
HP.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
HP.navigate().back();

}

Loop END
```

And "**Your LinkText**" is the data you are parsing.

So In the above code "no such element Exception" will only come in 1 place

1: `findElement(By.linkText("**Your LinkText**")`

Now in your code you have used `implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);`i multiple places which is not needed.

```
WebElement linkElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 30))
          .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.linkText("THE Linked Text You Entering")));
linkElement .click();
```

In above way you will save execution time and no such Element Exception will not come.

As per your need you can increase the `WebDriverWait` time limit and `ExpectedConditions` method like `isDisplayed()`, `isEnabled` etc....

Comment: Did you try above way of ExpectedCondition wait ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you so much for all, i came up with solution.
Code:

```
 public class Homepage {
 public static void LoadDistrict(WebDriver HP, String district){
    HP.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    HP.findElement(By.linkText(district)).click();
    HP.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    HP.navigate().back();
  }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    WebDriver HP=new ChromeDriver();
    HP.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    HP.get("https://********/");
    LoadDistrict(HP, "Northland");
    LoadDistrict(HP, "Auckland");
    LoadDistrict(HP, "Waikato");
    LoadDistrict(HP, "Bay of Plenty");
    LoadDistrict(HP, "Gisborne");
    LoadDistrict(HP, "Hawkes Bay");
    LoadDistrict(HP, "Taranaki");
    LoadDistrict(HP, "Wanganui");
    LoadDistrict(HP, "Manawatu");
    LoadDistrict(HP, "Wairarapa");
    LoadDistrict(HP, "Wellington");
    HP.close();
  }
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

As you stated, it could be due to loading times. By simply adding another

```
HP.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

after each

```
HP.navigate().back();
```

it should work, even though it'd wait quite a long time. Maybe make it with like 5 seconds.

EDIT: As stated in the other answers, the given line does not actually wait. I thought that, so this answer does not work. Try to look for the docs and replace the lines with a command that actually makes it wait (or use Thread.sleep(int) if you can).

Comment: I have given  different time interval: HP.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);HP.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);HP.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS); --------- nothing works for me

Comment: i am very sure there is no issue in the code but there is some time interval issue but don't know how to solve

Answer (score -1):

Hi i don't no that my solution is the best practice but i am pretty sure that this would work out for u

You can Do like this Create a function click on a link use try and catch if the link is not found refresh the page set and counter for 3 times and refresh the page even after refresh link is not found means throw the error worked perfectly for me 
write the same function for all the links which you want to test
And use the Wait Where your  code needs in the below Function so that you don't need to refresh 3 times

```
public void click_northland(){
       int Pagerefresh=0;
       String revtext=null;
       for(Pagerefresh=0;Pagerefresh<3;Pagerefresh++){
        try{
        HP.findElement(By.linkText("Northland")).click();
        HP.navigate().back();
        Pagerefresh=4;
        }
        catch(Exception e){
         HP.navigate().refresh();
       }
    }
    if(Pagerefresh==3){
        System.out.println("Error In Finding the link")
    }
}
```

Thanks,

Let me know if this works out for you.